# jQuery plugin to filter a list of li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a plugin that filter an li elements.

**jquery.livefilter.js**:

```
/*
* jQuery.liveFilter
*
* Copyright (c) 2009 Mike Merritt
*
* Forked by Lim Chee Aun (cheeaun.com)
* 
*/

(function($){
$.fn.liveFilter = function(inputEl, filterEl, options){
    var defaults = {
        filterChildSelector: null,
        filter: function(el, val){
            return $(el).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        },
        before: function(){},
        after: function(){}
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    var el = $(this).find(filterEl);
    if (options.filterChildSelector) el = el.find(options.filterChildSelector);

    var filter = options.filter;
    $(inputEl).keyup(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        var contains = el.filter(function(){
            return filter(this, val);
        });
        var containsNot = el.not(contains);
        if (options.filterChildSelector){
            contains = contains.parents(filterEl);
            containsNot = containsNot.parents(filterEl).hide();
        }

        options.before.call(this, contains, containsNot);

        contains.show();
        containsNot.hide();

        if (val === '') {
            contains.show();
            containsNot.show();
        }

        options.after.call(this, contains, containsNot);
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.livefilter.js"></script>
<script>
     $(function(){
         $('#livefilter-list').liveFilter('#livefilter-input', 'li', {
         filterChildSelector: 'a'
         });
     });
 </script>

 <div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><label for="livefilter-input">Search...</label></legend>
        <input id="livefilter-input" type="text" value="">
            <ul id="livefilter-list">
                <li><a href="#">cool</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">nice</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">interesting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">javascript</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">css</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">html</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">script</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">international</a></li>
            </ul>
     </fieldset>
 </div>
```

This code works great, but only with static li elements, like the li tags up there.
I have a jQuery function that append to ul tag many li elements. But, in this case, doesn't work

My code:

```
<div id="users" class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <ul id="livefilter-list" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <li><a>Ciao</a></li>
                                    <li><a>Come</a></li>
                                    <li><a>Stai</a></li>
                                </ul>                                    
                            </div>
```

jQuery:

```
for (var i in arr) {
                $('#users').append('<li data-user="' + arr[i].id + '"><a href="#" style="color: black">' + arr[i].name + '</a></li>');
            }
```

How can I resolve?

**UPDATE:**

```
<ul id="livefilter-list" class="nav nav-second-level" aria-expanded="true">
    <li><a>Hey</a></li>
    <li><a>How are</a></li>
    <li><a>you?</a></li>
</ul>
```

I append others li element with:

```
 for (var i in arr) {
     $('#livefilter-list').append('<li data-user="' + arr[i].id + '"><a href="#" style="color: black">' + arr[i].name + '</a></li>');
 }
```

and then:

```
$(function () {
    $('#livefilter-list').liveFilter('#livefilter-input', 'li', {
        filterChildSelector: 'a'
    });
});
```

With "Hey", "How are" and "you?" works. But with the li elements added with jQuery not. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax :

```
$(function (){...});
```

makes the anonymous function passed in parameter executed as soon as the dom is loaded. This means :

```
function () {
    $('#livefilter-list').liveFilter('#livefilter-input', 'li', {
    filterChildSelector: 'a'
}
```

is run before the for loop apending elements to the livefilter-list :

```
for (var i in arr) {
    $('#livefilter-list').append('<li data-user="' + arr[i].id + '"><a href="#" style="color: black">' + arr[i].name + '</a></li>');
}
```

I suggest you try to call liveFilter once the elements are appended to the livefilter-list :

```
for (var i in arr) {
    $('#livefilter-list').append('<li data-user="' + arr[i].id + '"><a href="#" style="color: black">' + arr[i].name + '</a></li>');
}
$('#livefilter-list').liveFilter('#livefilter-input', 'li', {
    filterChildSelector: 'a'
});
```

Comment: @DavideFruci - works so long as you add the elements before initialising the plugin - if you ever decide to add elements after the plugin in initialised it will still fail. See my answer for why.

Answer (score 1):

As your `ul` is `#livefilter-list`, you should use:

```
for (var i in arr) {
                $('#livefilter-list').append('<li data-user="' + arr[i].id + '"><a href="#" style="color: black">' + arr[i].name + '</a></li>');
            }
```

So it'll append `li` to `<ul id="livefilter-list" aria-expanded="true">`, not `<div id="users" class="nav nav-second-level">`

As your `liveFilter` is register to `li` under `#livefilter-input`, you can't have effect on `#user > li`, which become sibling of `#livefilter-input`.

Edit:

By the source code of `jQuery.liveFilt`,

```
    var el = $(this).find(filterEl);
    if (options.filterChildSelector) el = el.find(options.filterChildSelector);
```

it caches the element when created, and will not monitor further add/remove of the monitor target anymore, so it won't filter out any `li` added after its initialization.

You can tweak its code to force it get the newest element when filter is about to happen:

```
    var el = $(this).find(filterEl);
    if (options.filterChildSelector) el = el.find(options.filterChildSelector);
var self = this;
    var filter = options.filter;
    $(inputEl).keyup(function(){
      el = $(self).find(filterEl);
    if (options.filterChildSelector) el = el.find(options.filterChildSelector);  
        var val = $(this).val();
        var contains = el.filter(function(){
            return filter(this, val);
        });
        var containsNot = el.not(contains);
        if (options.filterChildSelector){
            contains = contains.parents(filterEl);
            containsNot = containsNot.parents(filterEl).hide();
        }

        options.before.call(this, contains, containsNot);

        contains.show();
        containsNot.hide();

        if (val === '') {
            contains.show();
            containsNot.show();
        }

        options.after.call(this, contains, containsNot);
```

So now it works. See [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kQv3Ub8e2Ie3uLq4SFyk?p=preview)

Comment: @DavideFruci check the source code, it's issue is from the lib.

Answer (score 0):

You are finding the filter elements once, and only once:

```
var el = $(this).find(filterEl);
if (options.filterChildSelector) el = el.find(options.filterChildSelector);
```

Later, on `keyup` you use this variable `el` to further filter the elements, however if you have added any new `li` between intialising the plugin, and pressing a key, the new elements are not included in the pre-defined list `el`.

The answer is to look for elements live on each `keyup` and not cache it away in a variable.

That should be as easy as wrapping the above 2 lines in a function:

```
function getFilterElements(){
    var el = $(this).find(filterEl);
    if (options.filterChildSelector) el = el.find(options.filterChildSelector);
    return el;
}
```

And calling that later in `keyup`:

```
var self = this;
$(inputEl).keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var el = getFilterElements.call(self)
    var contains = el.filter(function(){
        return filter(this, val);
    });
    ...
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/56xsvosq/